# How to use count with multiple tables in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three database tables :

Tickets : it contains tow `columns id`, `title`

Offers : it contains three `columns id`, `title`, `ticket_id`, `accepted_offer_id`

Accepted offers : it contains tow `columns id`, `result`

`accepted_offer_id` is a foreign key of `accepted_offer`

`ticket_id` is foreign key of `Tickets`

I let my users add tickets each ticket contains a lot of offers and each offer will finally had a result win or lost or cancelled or waiting.

the ticket considered finished if there is no waiting offers (all offers won or lost or cancelled).

I want to count the number of the finished tickets `count(id) from tickets` for all the tickets that all thier offers has already a result (not waiting).

I could use the following query to get all the finished tickets but I can not count them until now using a single query with `count` function:

```
SELECT t.id, 
o.ticket_id, 
sum(case when a.result = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ticket_status 
FROM offers o 
INNER JOIN accepted_offers a ON a.id = o.accepted_offer_id
INNER JOIN tickets t ON t.id = o.ticket_id
WHERE t.user_id = $user_id 
GROUP BY o.ticket_id HAVING ticket_status = 0
```

each 0 added to the sum mean that this offer is in waiting state so for each ticket if the ticket_status equal to zero it means it has no waiting offers which considered as finished ticket

I want to use `count` function to find the count of this finished ticket directly without bringing all these information . Is it possible?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, 
o.ticket_id, 
count(if(a.result = 0)) as ticket_status 
FROM offers o 
INNER JOIN accepted_offers a ON a.id = o.accepted_offer_id
INNER JOIN tickets t ON t.id = o.ticket_id
WHERE t.user_id = $user_id 
GROUP BY o.ticket_id HAVING ticket_status = 0
```

Try this